# Action of space in a sed command

Tags: sed

I'm refactoring some shell scripts, and I ran into a sed command like this:

```
sed -i "/^$t=/ s/^$t=.*$/$str/" $fil
```

I understand what the substitution does. and I can see the result of that, but I'm wondering what the part of the command before the space does.  It looks like a simple match but that seems quite unnecessary.

Comment: yup, it is trying to [perform substitution only on lines matching the pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3120/address-and-address-range/13753/lines-matching-regular-expression-pattern#t=201610210202228277392) - in this case `/^$t=/` ... apparently this would be faster as sed need not go for substitution if a line doesn't match the pattern.. will depend on file size and how many lines match this pattern and all..

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like the space is more or less equivalent to a logical AND, is that correct?

Comment: that space is not required at all, only a syntactic sugar.. `sed -i "/^$t=/s/^$t=.*$/$str/" $fil` will also work... the logic is pretty clear, if a line matches the pattern, only then perform substitution.. another example: `echo 'cat and dog animal' | sed '/animal/s/cat/CAT/'`

Answer (score 0):

You are right: `sed '/pattern/ s/find/replace/'` executes the replacement in the lines matching `/pattern/`.

In [3.1. How sed works](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) we read:

> sed maintains two data buffers: the active pattern space, and the auxiliary hold space. Both are initially empty.
>
> sed operates by performing the following cycle on each line of input: first, sed reads one line from the input stream, removes any trailing newline, and places it in the pattern space. Then commands are executed; each command can have an address associated to it: addresses are a kind of condition code, and a command is only executed if the condition is verified before the command is to be executed.

Then we see:

> 3.2 Selecting lines with sed
>
> ```
> /regexp/
> ```
>
> This will select any line which matches the regular expression regexp. If regexp itself includes any / characters, each must be escaped by a backslash ().
>   The empty regular expression ‘//’ repeats the last regular expression match (the same holds if the empty regular expression is passed to the s command). Note that modifiers to regular expressions are evaluated when the regular expression is compiled, thus it is invalid to specify them together with the empty regular expression.

And finally the `s/` expression is defined in:

> 3.5 The s Command
>
> The syntax of the s (as in substitute) command is ‘s/regexp/replacement/flags’. The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command. The / character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the regexp or replacement only if it is preceded by a \ character.